# Error: This socket is closed

Tags: node.js

I am currently new on Node.js. I am facing problem with following exception. Any idea what actually, this exception mean and what solution is required..????

```
Error: This socket is closed. 
    at WriteStream.Socket._write (net.js:635:19) 
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:219:10) 
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:209:5) 
    at WriteStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:180:11) 
    at WriteStream.Socket.write (net.js:613:40)       
    at Console.log (/home/ubuntu/svnrepo/FoodiptoBackend/TransactionManagement/node_modules/winston/lib/winston/transports/console.js:78:20) 
    at emit (/home/ubuntu/svnrepo/FoodiptoBackend/TransactionManagement/node_modules/winston/lib/winston/logger.js:174:17) 
    at /home/ubuntu/svnrepo/FoodiptoBackend/TransactionManagement/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:108:13 
    at Array.forEach (native) 
    at _each (/home/ubuntu/svnrepo/FoodiptoBackend/TransactionManagement/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:32:24) 
    at Object.async.each (/home/ubuntu/svnrepo/FoodiptoBackend/TransactionManagement/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:107:9) 
    at Logger.log (/home/ubuntu/svnrepo/FoodiptoBackend/TransactionManagement/node_modules/winston/lib/winston/logger.js:202:9)
```

Here is My Code for logger which is used in my application.

```
var winston = require("winston");
var moment = require("moment");

//Note : create directory for logs manually
var logFileName = process.cwd() + '/logs/' + moment().utc().format("YYYYMMDD") +   '.log';

var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
    transports: [
        new (winston.transports.Console)(),
        new (winston.transports.File)({
            filename: logFileName,
            handleExceptions: true, //same file shall be used for handling info as well as  exception logs
            json: true,
            maxsize: 5242880,
            timestamp: true
        })
    ],
    exitOnError: false //prevent exit if an uncaught exception occurs
});

//
// Handle errors
//
logger.on('error', function (err) {
    //console.log("Error occured while logging");
});

module.exports = logger;
```

Comment: Or find out why the other end of the socket is closing it.  Not much we can do without seeing the actual code and knowing more about the conditions/sequence of operations that cause this.

Comment: I think this is the problem with module, because this exception is occurring randomly. I don't have any track from where it's occurred.??

Comment: And another confusion is that, my code is working properly on my local machine but when ever I deploy my services on server it generate exception randomly..??

Answer (score 0):

The mentioned `console.js:78:20` actually calls `process.stderr.write`.
Next we see that it calls a socket: `WriteStream.Socket.write (net.js:613:40)`

That looks confusing at first. Why would `process.stderr` need a socket?

Well, that's actually how the `stderr` works in node.js, with the major exception being a `stderr` which outputs directly to a file.

What I think happens here, only is a visible error because you have 2 loggers.

1. The moment your applications exits, it disconnects the console socket first.
2. Then it continues to write some log messages.
3. And of course those log statements cannot be sent to your console, because the socket is disconnected now. Resulting in an error.
4. However, the statements can still be sent to your file logger, because it closes slightly later.

So, why does it continue to send some log messages after closing the socket ?
I'm not 100% sure.

- It could be something in your code.
- It could be due to an "uncaught exception handler".
- It could be due to something in your `logger.on(...)`.
- Perhaps you're using `logger.stream` somewhere.

Whatever may be the reason. It's interesting to know that since this post, the code has been rewritten internally, and no longer uses `process.stderr` directly. Perhaps it was just a `winston` bug, which could be solved by now.